# MobileAppTracking doesn't work

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, tracking

I use this tutorial for testing tracking of my app: http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/22561876-Testing-iOS-SDK-integration

It works good when I use Tracking Link, but then no logs in server side of MAT.

Some code (at Awake of my gameobject Game):

```
#if UNITY_IOS
    initNativeCode(AdvertiserId, ConversionKey);

    trackInstall();
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `setAllowDuplicateRequests` set to `true`? If not, your install is probably being thrown away as a duplicate. See http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/23835788-Unity-Plugin-v1-1

Alternately, you can use a testing profile (set it up in the platform).